# How to generate dll with header only

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, dll

I have created a project, output of which is dll. I put all implementations in header(.h) and didn't add the corresponding cpp. Then I built the project, it didn't generate any dll, but if I added the corresponding cpp even this cpp is empty, VS can generate dll. Why would this happen?

Comment: A header file isn't directly compileable. The compiler only compiles `.c` and `.cpp` files - with no `.cpp` files there's no compiler input so it quits without generating any output.

Comment: Even if your `.cpp` file was empty, you probably have Precompiled Headers enabled, so there's actually more input to your compiler than you think. See what the actual command-line is that VS generates and you'll see it.

Comment: Therefore, even I don't need .cpp file, I need to add one to make compile happen? Is there any more elegant method?

Comment: Move your executable code (definitions, not declarations) to the `.cpp` file and write code idiomatically - executable code should generally not exist in header files. Template definitions are one of the few exceptions (but template instantiations should be in `.cpp` files).

Comment: If you don't need `.cpp`, why do you need `.dll`?